# Intel xdk notification alert not working with AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, intel-xdk

I using AJAX to call MySQL select connection to include items on my data base.
I want add an alert notification when AJAX complete successfully but it doesn't working.

Success: function (data) { navigator.notification.alert("OK","OK","OK")}

The function with AJAX is working but the notification do not appear.
Obs: I have been added NOTIFICATION plugin.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
navigator.notification.alert("OK",function(){},"Title");
```

second param for `navigator.notification.alert` is a callback function